How to divide a rectangular box into smaller rectangular boxes?
I am trying to divide a rectangular box into smaller rectangular boxes like this picture

I tried
a = 3;
b = 6;
c = 4;
c1 = Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}, Boxed -> False];
c2 = Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c/2}]}, Boxed -> False];
c3 = Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{0, 0, c/2}, {a, b, c}]}, Boxed -> False];
GraphicsRow[{c1, c2, c3}]


How can I get like my sreenshot?

I think that you have to use RegionPlot3D.

Unless you have to do reproduce this figure in ten different ways, I would take the simple minded approach of just drawing the lines individually. I'd draw a picture and label the vertices. I'd use the labels as my variables. I'd start with a base point for a vertex and three vectors to represent the edges and use the vectors to construct the other vertices. To separate the pieces, I'd add offset vectors to the vertices. Or you could spend time coding and debugging a cute programmatic solution, because it's more fun to figure that out, even if it's less efficient.

TBH, when playing on this site, I'm tempted to post the cute solution, because actually I personally need to replicate the figure zero times and fun & learning are among my goals; when doing my own work, I tend to use the simple-minded approach.

Here is a tool box for what you want.
"div" will split a cuboid: {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 2}} n times:
div[n_] := 
 Module[{box = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 2}}}, z = 0, dz = 0.3, t1, t2, f},
  f = (t1 = (#[[2, 3]] - #[[1, 3]])/2; t2 = z; 
     z += 2 t1 + 2 dz; {{Append[#[[1, 1 ;; 2]], t2], 
       Append[#[[2, 1 ;; 2]], t2 + t1]}, {Append[#[[1, 1 ;; 2]], 
        t2 + t1 + dz], Append[#[[2, 1 ;; 2]], t2 + 2 t1 + dz]}}) &;
  Do[z = 0; box = Flatten[f /@ box, 1], n];
  box
  ]

Row[{Graphics3D[Cuboid @@@ div[1]], Graphics3D[Cuboid @@@ div[2]]}]


"dia" will split a cuboid diagonally and eventually shift one part against the other by "d":
dia[b_, d_ : 0] := Module[{t1, t2},
  t1 = {b[[1]], 
    Prepend[b[[1, 2 ;; 3]], b[[2, 1]]], {b[[1, 1]], b[[2, 2]], 
     b[[1, 3]]},
    Append[b[[1, 1 ;; 2]], b[[2, 3]]], {b[[2, 1]], b[[1, 2]], 
     b[[2, 3]]}, {b[[1, 1]], b[[2, 2]], b[[2, 3]]}};
  t2 = {Prepend[b[[1, 2 ;; 3]], b[[2, 1]]], {b[[1, 1]], b[[2, 2]], 
     b[[1, 3]]}, {b[[2, 1]], b[[2, 2]], b[[1, 3]]},
    {b[[2, 1]], b[[1, 2]], b[[2, 3]]}, {b[[1, 1]], b[[2, 2]], 
     b[[2, 3]]}, {b[[2, 1]], b[[2, 2]], b[[2, 3]]}};
  {t1, d {1, 1, 0}/Sqrt[2] + # & /@ t2}
  ]

Graphics3D[ Prism /@ dia[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}}] ]


Graphics3D[ Prism /@ dia[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}}, 0.3] ]


Or some combination thereof:
t = div[1];
t1 = Cuboid @@@ t;
t21 = Prism /@ dia[t[[1]]]; t21 = Translate[t21, {2, 0, 0}];

t22 = Translate[t1[[2]], {2, 0, 0}];

t3 = Prism /@ dia[t[[1]], 0.2]; t3 = Translate[t3, {4, 0, 0}];
Graphics3D[{t1, t21, t22, t3}]




Only draw the last picture.

Clear["Global`*"];
cuboid = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {8, 4, 5}];
normal = Cross[{8, 0, 0} - {0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 1}];
regs = RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@cuboid, 
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[#*normal, {8, 0, 0}], 
      PlotRange -> 10]] & /@ {1, -1};
regs = {TranslationTransform[-.3 Normalize@normal]@regs[[1]], 
   TranslationTransform[.3 Normalize@normal]@regs[[2]]};
DynamicModule[{point = 10 {Cos[2.3], 1.1, Sin[2.3]}, 
  vertical = {0, 0, 1}, angle = 8 Degree}, 
 Overlay[Graphics3D[#, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@point, 
     ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vertical, 
     ViewAngle -> Dynamic@angle] & /@ {{EdgeForm[
      AbsoluteThickness[2]], 
     regs}, {EdgeForm[
      Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
        AbsoluteDashing[{1, 8}, 0, "Round"]}], FaceForm[], regs}}, 
  All, 1]]


